# How to mock ServiceLocator ZF2?

Tags: php, zend-framework2, phpunit

Here is a Factory :

```
namespace Maintenance\Factory\View\Helper;

use Zend\ServiceManager\FactoryInterface;
use Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceLocatorInterface;
use Maintenance\View\Helper\SousMenuContrat;

class SousMenuContratFactory implements FactoryInterface
{
    public function createService(ServiceLocatorInterface $serviceLocator)
        {
            $realServiceLocator = $serviceLocator->getServiceLocator();

            $maiContratService = $realServiceLocator->get(
                'Maintenance\Service\Model\FMaiContratService'
            );   

            return new SousMenuContrat(
                $maiContratService
            );
        }
   }
```

I have to write some PHPUnit tests, I began to do so :

```
public function testCreateService()
    {
        $this->mockDriver = $this->getMock('Zend\Db\Adapter\Driver\DriverInterface');
        $this->mockConnection = $this->getMock('Zend\Db\Adapter\Driver\ConnectionInterface');
        $this->mockDriver->expects($this->any())->method('checkEnvironment')->will($this->returnValue(true));
        $this->mockDriver->expects($this->any())->method('getConnection')->will($this->returnValue($this->mockConnection));
        $this->mockPlatform = $this->getMock('Zend\Db\Adapter\Platform\PlatformInterface');
        $this->mockStatement = $this->getMock('Zend\Db\Adapter\Driver\StatementInterface');
        $this->mockDriver->expects($this->any())->method('createStatement')->will($this->returnValue($this->mockStatement));
        $this->adapter = new Adapter($this->mockDriver, $this->mockPlatform);
        $this->sql = new Sql($this->adapter);


        $mockTableGateway = $this->getMock('Zend\Db\TableGateway\TableGateway', array(), array(), '', false);

        $maiContratTable = $this->getMockBuilder('Maintenance\Model\BDD\FMaiContratTable')
            ->setMethods(array())
            ->setConstructorArgs(array($mockTableGateway, $this->adapter, $this->sql))
            ->getMock();


        $smMock = $this->getMockBuilder('Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceManager')
                       ->setMethods(array('get'))
                       ->getMock();

        $smMock->expects($this->at(0))
            ->method('get')
            ->with('Maintenance\Service\Model\FMaiContratService')
            ->will($this->returnValue(new FMaiContratService($maiContratTable)));

        $factory = new SousMenuContratFactory();
        $runner = $factory->createService($smMock);
    }
```

But I got some problems. This tells me :

> Call to undefined method Mock_ServiceManager_3ed93deb::getServiceLocator()

What have I misunderstood ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your factory you call:

```
$realServiceLocator = $serviceLocator->getServiceLocator();
```

But you defined:

```
$smMock->expects($this->at(0))
        ->method('get')
```

The ServiceLocator passed to your factory usually does not have the method `getServiceLocator` because it already is the service locator. (**Edit:** Scratch that, PluginManagers do!) Instead use:

```
public function createService(ServiceLocatorInterface $serviceLocator)
{
    $maiContratService = $serviceLocator->get(
        'Maintenance\Service\Model\FMaiContratService'
    );   

    return new SousMenuContrat(
        $maiContratService
    );
}
```

**Edit:** Plugin factories are another thing, here's the test code:

```
public function testCreateService()
{
    $maiContractServiceMock = $this->getMockBuilder('Maintenance\Service\Model\FMaiContratService')
        ->disableOriginalConstructor()
        ->getMock();
    // if you do something with FMaiContratService in the constructor of SousMenuContrat,
    // mock more methods here

    $smMock = $this->getMockBuilder('Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceManager')
        ->setMethods(array('get'))
        ->getMock();
    $smMock->expects($this->at(0))
        ->method('get')
        ->with('Maintenance\Service\Model\FMaiContratService')
        ->will($this->returnValue($maiContractServiceMock));

    $hpmMock = $this->getMockBuilder('Zend\View\HelperPluginManager')
        ->setMethods(array('getServiceLocator'))
        ->getMock();
    $hpmMock->expects($this->any())
        ->method('getServiceLocator')
        ->will($this->returnValue($smMock));

    $factory = new SousMenuContratFactory();
    $runner = $factory->createService($hpmMock);
}
```

In this case, you need a mock of the plugin manager, returning another service locator if `getServiceLocator` is called. Désolé!

Comment: This asks me FMaiContratService's arguments, but i don't really call the FMaiContratService, I call the Factory whichs calls the FMaiContratService (via the ServiceManager)...

Comment: I'm not sure if I get you here, it works fine for me and I don't get an error. You get the error because the mock you passed to `createService()` didn't know about the method `getServiceLocator()` - which is good because the ServiceLocatorInterface doesn't contain such a method. And the method `get('Maintenance\...')` returns the required instance of `FMaiContratService`, doesn't it?

Comment: Yes, but FMaiContratService is called by a factory in module.config.php, if I delete "$realServiceLocator = $serviceLocator->getServiceLocator();" this asks me for FMaiContratService's arguements in my web application ... it's my factory's job ! So I think my application doesn't know anymore my factory.

Comment: Well first of all, create a mock of `FMaiContratService` as well and don't instantiate it in your test. It's constructor should not be tested. You can also use `getMockBuilder("...")->disableOriginalConstructor()` to disable the constructor. Will make your test much easier I guess.

Comment: Second: If you really need `$realServiceLocator = $serviceLocator->getServiceLocator();` in your code in order to make it work in production, create another mock with the method `getServiceLocator()` returning your `$smMock`. I don't know why you should need this, but hey, I don't know everything about Zend 2 either!

Comment: Well I think we don't undersatnd each other ... Is this clear that if I delete "$realServiceLocator = $serviceLocator->getServiceLocator();" this stops working IN MY WEB APPLICATION, not in my tests ?

Comment: See the second comment for that :-) I'll edit the answer

Comment: Thanks, I'll see what I need to instanciate another mock. Geez there is so lack of documentation ....

Comment: Btw. I'm curious, may I see your entire factory definition? I want to know which class it extends. And please dump `var_dump(get_class($serviceLocator))` as well

Comment: I edited the part concerning the factory. My var_dump shows : string(29) "Zend\View\HelperPluginManager"

Comment: Well THAT makes sense! Thanks very much! Creating factories for plugins is another thing, I just assumed you are creating an ordinary factory!